# Ударение в имени Фока

Tags: фонетика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно ставить ударение в имени Фока? Мне всегда казалось, что ударение на О, но потом где-то попался вариант ФокА.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре ударений (2009 год) дается вариант ФОка, но в скобках пометка (византийский император).